# Does scp block server functions?

Tags: performance, node.js, scp

I have a node.js application server. It serves my api and dynamic web pages. The database is not on the server.

I want to continuously scp files into the server. Would that cause slow downs or block web requests or would it only have a minor impact?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the amount of data being transferred, the available bandwidth to the server and the speed of the transfer, it is all relative.

Comment: Indeed; even if it doesn't block the Node.js event loop, if you saturate the network it can degrade the performance of your application/server.

Comment: The amount of data being transferred is small. I'm using an amazon ec2 'small' instance and is transferring 20kb files every second. It sounds like it should be fine right?